# Not Able To Add Values inside a JSON object dynamicaally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to add objects to a JSON object  to be like

```
 var books = [{
                "no" : 1,
                "bookType":"fiction",
                "bookPrice": 60

            },{
                "no" : 2,
                "bookType":"fun",
                "bookPrice": 40

            }
            ....
  ]
```

but the out put is so different! can you please let me know how to fix this?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
         var books = [];
            $('.addItem').on('click', function() {
            var type = $(this).data('type');
            var price = $(this).data('price');
            books.push('{',type, '"',price,'"}'),
            console.log(books);
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addItem" data-type="fiction" data-price="50">Add Book</button>
<button class="addItem" data-type="fun" data-price="40">Add Book</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have inserted string instead of an object. You don't need to stringify an object in order to insert into an array. Array can hold objects.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         var books = [];
            $('.addItem').on('click', function() {
            var type = $(this).data('type');
            var price = $(this).data('price');
            books.push({
              "no":books.length,
              "bookType":type,
              "bookPrice":price
             });
            console.log(books);
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addItem" data-type="fiction" data-price="50">Add Book</button>
<button class="addItem" data-type="fun" data-price="40">Add Book</button>
```